# How parse xml sitemap with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simple-html-dom

I want to print values inside elemnts of `xml` file but i have a problem.

This xml sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/sitemap.xsl"?>
 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url><loc>https://www.example.com/1</loc></url>
  <url><loc>https://www.example.com/2</loc></url>
 </urlset>
```

and this is my code:

```
$url_sitemap = "file.xml";
$xml_sitemap = simplexml_load_file($url_sitemap);

foreach($xml_sitemap-> urlset -> url as $url){
 $link= $url->loc;
 print_r($link);
}
```

but i have this error: ****Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `print_r($xml_sitemap);` you'll see that it doesn't contain the `urlset`:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [loc] => https://www.example.com/1
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [loc] => https://www.example.com/2
                )

        )

)
```

You can then use

```
foreach ($xml_sitemap as $url) {
    echo $url->loc;
}
```

to output all `loc`s

Comment: why not "$xml_sitemap-> url as $url" ?

Comment: @Borja You could do that. Likely it was written this way in case more elements were present. That way only returns `url` elements.